# GRASS GIS: v.vect.stats aborts when working on a large(2GB) shapefile

Tags: gis, grass

I have a bunch of point shapefiles, each ~2-3GB, which I upload into GRASS GIS, to find the diversity of points in each cell of a gridded shapefile using 'v.vect.stats'.

This operation worked fine for smaller datasets(<2 GB). I'm not sure if it's because of the size, but I now get this message in the console:

```
v.vect.stats: spindex_rw.c:1362: rtree_get_node: Assertion `t->nb[level][which].n.level == level' failed.
```

Followed by:

```
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'd be grateful for any ideas on what could be causing this and how I can get around it.

EDIT: The above works on the same shapefile when I reduce the number of points in it. So I'm guessing this *is* an issue with the size of the file. Unfortunately, I cannot use a shapefile with reduced points because each point in a shapefile has a unique ID, so calculating the diversity of points needs to happen with all the points.

I tried setting GRASS_VECTOR_LOWMEM=1, so that GRASS uses less memory for the v.vect.stats operation, but this does not help. I get the same 'Aborted (core dumped)' message.